# How can i display a logo in Navigation Bar with ReactBootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I try to make a navbar with logo for my first website. The problem i face is the fact that the logo doesnt want to display at all. The only way it worked somehow was using the url link to some logo from internet. I have a logo and .js file in the same folder.

I did use:

```
"src=/michelinlogo.png"
```

The absolute path:
    /home/goteii/reactprojects/xxx/xxxx/src/Components/michelinlogo.png

And the relative path:
    src/Components/michelinlogo.png

```
export class NavBar extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <>
<Navbar bg="dark" style = {{height: "5em"}}>
<Navbar.Brand href="#home">
  <img
    alt="Michelin_logo"
    src="/michelinlogo.png"
    width="150"
    height="30"
    className="d-inline-block align-top"
  />
  {' Michelin App'}
</Navbar.Brand>
<Nav>
<Navbar.Brand href="#login" style= {{float:"right"}}>Login
</Navbar.Brand>
</Nav>
</Navbar>
```

I expected the logo displaying in my navbar instead i see alternative text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing the logo first:

```
import logo from './michelinlogo.png'; // If it's in the same folder as your component. Otherwise adjust the path

<Navbar.Brand href="#home">
  <img
    alt="Michelin_logo"
    src={logo}
    width="150"
    height="30"
    className="d-inline-block align-top"
  />
  {" Michelin App"}
</Navbar.Brand>
```

Comment: Actually worked out! Thank you a lot, feeling a bit ashamed I didnt figure it out by myself